# Powershell Restart Script

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm attempting to write a script that gives me a running list of computers whose name starts with SOU-C128*. I'm assigning the list to a variable and using it as input for the restart-computer cmdlet. However, I'm recieving the error provided:

```
restart-computer : Computer name @{Name=SOU-C127-04} cannot be resolved with the exception: One or more errors occurred..
At \\nas\user\IT\restart.ps1:2 char:1
+ restart-computer -computername $computers -force -wsmanauthentication ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{Name=SOU-C127-04}:String) [Restart-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddressResolutionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartComputerCommand
```

This is the script

```
$computers=Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "sou-c127*"} | Select -Property Name | Sort Name 
restart-computer -computername $computers -force -wsmanauthentication Kerberos
```

Please assist!

Thanks.

Comment: This is a common question.  `select -expand name` or `foreach-object name`

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate fix would be to use `$computers.name` or, expand the property in your `Get-ADComputer` by using `Select-Objet -ExpandProperty 'Name'`; `foreach name` would suffice too.

Wanted to suggest something though. In PowerShell when you're filtering, you always want to filter as far left as possible. This can become *computationally expensive* running a pipeline filter such as `Where-Object` on a large list. In your case: `Get-ADComputer -Filter *`, you're filtering for every computer, then filtering again. You can cut that out by filtering using the filter in your `Get-ADComputer` cmdlet to begin with:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'sou-c127*'" | Sort-Object -Property 'Name'
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computers.Name
```